# Native messaging between edge extension and a NON-UWP application

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, uwp, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I have a chrome extension which talks to my legacy background windows application using native proxy. Now I am supposed to make the same extension for edge. But edge does not support native proxy. It uses appService API to communicate with UWP applications. If, go with this approach, I need to convert my background application to an UWP application. so I want to know Is there any way where my edge extension can communicate with my existing legacy application?

I have one more doubt, now I publish my chrome extension in chrome extension store, this chrome extension is one client for my background application, we have mobile phone as another client. So while installing my application I can opt for chrome extension (it is not mandatory to have chrome extension for application to work). this way, application is not dependent on extension and vice versa.  Can I upload only edge extension to edge extension store separately which can talk to my application running in system.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, you'll need to convert your background application to a UWP application by using the Desktop Bridge. See [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare) on how to start this process.

As for publishing a native messaging app to the store as two pieces (the extension and the UWP component), this can be done if the native messaging app extension package contains your extension and a UWP AppService that acts as a "bridge" to enable communication between it and your standalone UWP app. This standalone UWP app would be a separate package.